# Can I increase the power rating of a film resistor if I increase the cooling?

Tags: resistors, heatsink

I am trying to apply 1 kW of heat to an area of 10x10 mm and I am considering using a panel mounted film resistor.

One that meets my power requirements doesn't exist so I am wondering if I can go above the normal power rating if I sufficiently cool the resistor.

Could I use a lower powered one as long as the heat was adequately removed?

(I should say the point of this is I am developing a heat sink for high powered electronics and the temperature of the resistor wouldn't go above the normal recommended temperature)

Comment: I expect that many resistors will be sacrificed in this development - why not try it? Maybe start out trying to remove 50 W from such a small area and work your way up.

Comment: Please provide a link to a device that you think might be suitable or just read its data sheet.

Comment: is that heat flow not hotter than surface of the sun?

Comment: sun is about 0.8million mile diameter; at earth, that sphere is 93Million miles radii, or 180Million mile diameter; heat flux onto our earth (thru our atmosphere) is 1,000 watts/square meter; scaling that back to surface of sun, using [180Million/0.8Million]^2, is about 1,000watts / 60,000th of meter or about 4millimeter by 4millimeter. Thus you want HOTTER than the sun, even before accounting for atmospheric absorption.

Comment: I have found this paper which is doing something similar to what i want to do:
file:///C:/Users/Andrew%20Anderson/Downloads/Super_cooling_structures_for_power_electronics.pdf

Comment: I'm not going to check your maths but 1kw per 4x4mm is a sixth of what I am aiming to do

Comment: @AndrewAnderson We'll need the info on how to connect to your C: drive to be able to read that ;)

Comment: Well @analogsystemsrf, maybe adequately heatsinking the Sun might do the trick... :P

Comment: Liquid-nitrogen cooling perhaps?

Comment: @AndrewMorton haha I was viewing it in my browser and didn't even notice. 
https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1665571

Comment: Have you checked with Isabellenhüette?

Comment: @rdtsc I'm not going that far but I am using refrigerants

Comment: @winny I'm sorry I don't know who/what that is

Comment: @AndrewMorton It's a manufacturer of high-power and low-resistance resistors; their toll-free phone number is appropriately enough 1-800-LOW-OHMS

Comment: @AndrewMorton thanks when i googled it a conference came up and I didn't notice it was a product manufacturer hosting it

Answer (score 2):

For a 100’C rise per 1kW input you would need a CPU style heat sink with 0.1’C/W thermal resistance with size and force air of a super cooler heatsink.  These are typical much larger(10x)  than your allocated area and have >10m/s air velocity over a large number of fins.

- water cooling would be necessary to reduce the area to 1 cm^2 with a very efficient heat exchanger.

Comment: Thanks. The purpose of my project is to develop a new kind of cooling device for high powered electronics and I can't think of any reason why you couldn't superrate the resistor as long as it was kept cool

Comment: Ceramics may operate at 150’C and some higher. But do the math on thermal resistance, your miserly area needs a super cooler like a copper sponge heat water cooler to achieve <=100’C rise at max ambient (TBD)

Answer (score 1):

In general, yes you can push a resistor beyond its ratings just as you would a transistor.  We have cooled inductors and capacitors as well.  However, the devil is in the details.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I generally wanted to know. I just don't know if there was any other issues I would encounter other than heat generation

Answer (score 0):

In general, no you cannot operate a device beyond its specified maximum operating conditions without risking failure.

Remember that the power rating of a resistor is not the only limitation. There are also limits on the maximum current and the maximum voltage. If you are attempting to dissipate 1kW through a resistor then either your voltage or current are probably very high.

Comment: I am aware of maximum voltage being an issue because of shorting and maximum power due to heat but if that is properly dissipated so the resistor stays in a safe operating temperature I can't see why it wouldn't work. Are there other issues I'm not aware of?

Comment: Yes, **maximum current**. I am also doubtful that you can really keep the entire body of the resistor within its specified operating temperature range at 1kW.

Comment: Can you explain what would happen if I exceeded the maximum current other than excessive heat? Right now there isn't anything in the world that could keep it within range. That's what my research is aiming to do :)

Comment: For thin film conductors with very high current density you may see electromigration, where the electron flux literally moves the metal atoms around. The current density is higher where the metallization is thinner, so any non-uniformity in the metal will exacerbate and accelerate the problem. And remember that you must keep the **entire structure** below the maximum temperature...you can't allow localized heating inside the structure or you risk normal fusing of the conductors. You really haven't provided anywhere near enough information to give you a good answer.